# XAML binding to IsChecked for all ToggleButtons in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, togglebutton

I have seen many questions similar to mine but none that solves or addresses my problem.

What I have is a group of toggle buttons that exist inside of an ItemsControl, and these toggle buttons are created dynamically at run time based off of the number of people inside of an index that the ItemSource of the ItemsControl is bound to. When these toggle buttons are clicked in the UI, some filtering is done based on the person's name. Multiple buttons or even all the buttons can be selected if so desired. There is also a "clear" button which simply removes all filtering and should reset the toggle button IsClicked states.

My problem is that when I click the clear button, all of the toggle buttons that were clicked remain clicked. I am trying to have the clear button reset every ToggleButton's IsClicked value to false by binding the IsClicked value to a property that is managed in the code, but no matter what I try I cannot get this to work.

Code:

Xaml

```
<Button Content="Clear Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Click="ClearClick"/>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource peopleSorted}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton Name="toggleButton" Margin="0,0,5,0" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

c# ViewModel:

```
 private void ClearClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.m_viewModel.ClearFiltering();
        }
```

C# model:

```
 public bool IsChecked
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.m_isChecked;
                }

                set
                {
                    this.m_isChecked = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }private bool m_isChecked;

public void ClearFiltering()
        {
            m_hashTable.Clear();
            this.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

I am pretty stuck. I feel like the reason the binding isn't working is that the toggle buttons are dynamically created inside of an ItemsControl, but I am not sure if that's what's wrong or how to fix it if it is.

## UPDATE

I was able to work around this by doing a swap and swap-back on the data of observable collection that the ToggleButtons ItemsControl is bound to, which triggered the OnPropertyChanged for the entire collection of toggle buttons, thus resetting that part of the UI. It is a simple hack with almost no overhead and four lines of code, but doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `ClearFiltering()` on every item in `peopleSorted`?

Comment: I think you need the exact instance of the class to be able to change those values. If you don't have the exact instance the values won't change. To be able to fully understand your problem, provide complete code relating to your question.

Comment: I tried including more code. ClearFiltering() simply clears some colors off the UI, it does not operate on peopleSorted nor does it need to. That works fine and is unrelated to my toggle button issue, so  the code that does that is not shown.

Comment: For each item, `ToggleButton.IsChecked` is bound to the `IsChecked` property of the item, which is cleared by the `ClearFiltering()` method of that item. You wrote, *"There is also a "clear" button which simply removes all filtering and should reset the toggle button IsClicked states."* What is the problem you are trying to solve here? Are the model and the viewmodel different classes? Does each have a totally unrelated `IsChecked` property, and you're clearing the wrong one?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett No the IsChecked is not unrelated for each class, and yes the model and viewmodel are separate classes. I have plenty of binding properties in the model that are implemented the same way as IsChecked that work just fine. Sorry if this wasn't clear but the problem is that the ClearFiltering method *should* reset the toggle buttons but doesn't. Based on your comment, should IsChecked be named something else? You make it sound like I am binding the property of the toggle button to itself